# How i use mashape curl on php

Tags: php, curl, mashape

How i use it on php with curl?

```
curl --get --include 'https://consulta-situacao-cpf-cnpj.p.mashape.com/consultaSituacaoCNPJ?cnpj={cnpj}' \
  -H 'X-Mashape-Key: MYKEY'
```

I know this is wrong but i try this (I replace MY KEY and MY CPF for real values):

```
<?php
$cpf = "MY CPF";
$url = "https://consulta-situacao-cpf-cnpj.p.mashape.com/consultaSituacaoCPF?cpf=".$cpf;
$data = array('X-Mashape-Key' => 'MY KEY'); //My Key

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$name = trim(curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the man page for `curl` you'll see that the `-H` option adds a header, nothing to do with POST data. To do the same in PHP, set the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option:

```
<?php
$cpf = "MY CPF";
$url = "https://consulta-situacao-cpf-cnpj.p.mashape.com/consultaSituacaoCPF?cpf=".$cpf;
$headers = array("X-Mashape-Key: MY KEY"); //My Key

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$name = trim(curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

echo $name;
?>
```